# C#: Properties Map

Tags: c#

Is there a PropertiesMap in C# which exposes methods like GetDouble(string), GetDateTime(string), etc..?

`IDictionary<string,string>` forces users to take care of type conversion.

Comment: `IDictionary<string, string>` is not forcing you to take care of anything, *your choice to use* `IDictionary<string, string>` to store inherently non-string data might be forcing your hand.

Comment: If you are actually looking to store different types in your dictionary, you'd probably be better off using the non-generic form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Dictionary class and add extension methods for all data types that you wanr to have Get method, or add a generic Get method and use it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Get<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, string key)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        }

        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }

        return (T)dictionary[key];
    }
}
```

You even can create alias for the `Dictionary<string, object>` type:

```
using PropertiesMap = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

And usage of this:

```
PropertiesMap pm = new PropertiesMap { { "1", 1 }, { "2", DateTime.Now }};
Console.WriteLine(pm.Get<int>("1"));
Console.WriteLine(pm.Get<DateTime>("2"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is ExpandoObject and it has a very clean syntax.

```
dynamic propertyMap = new ExpandoObject();
var item = propertyMap as IDictionary<String, object>;

item["A"] = DateTime.Now;
item["B"] = "New val 2";
propertyMap.C = 1234

Console.WriteLine(propertyMap.A);
Console.WriteLine(propertyMap.B);    
Console.WriteLine(propertyMap.C);
```

Comment: +1, we never think of the "dynamic" keyword. I'm sure it's not so evil if used scarsely

Comment: What's the difference between 'ExpandoObject' and 'Dictionary<string,object>'?

Comment: @erikH look at the syntax. You can directly access properties without casting them with ExpandoObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Convert`, it can handle a lot of the conversions you will need.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(string value) //about 7 overloads
Convert.ToInt32(string value)
Convert.ToDouble(string value)
```

It has a lot of options for conversions, with plenty of overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `Convert.ToXXX`? Not sure what your question has to do with `IDictionary<string, string>` though...

See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary<string,object>` can store anything without conversion. However you will have to cast when retrieving the values:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict.Add("Name", "John");
dict.Add("Age", 20);
...
string name = (string)dict["Name"];
int age = (int)dict["Age"];
```